# Why don't function pointer arguments affect memory size?

Tags: c++, memory, function-pointers, sizeof

Recently I was looking at the src code for the gl3w library. I noticed that it used a new type of structure for me: a `union`. I found out that a `union` was a way for multiple data types to exist in the same place. But what I noticed was that it was switching between the type without reassigning values. It was switching from an array of pure c function pointers and a struct of function pointers with different amounts of arguments. So I did a little bit of testing:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*PUREPROC)();
typedef void (*ARGSPROC)(int, int *);

int main() {
     std::cout << "PUREPROC's size is: " << sizeof(PUREPROC) << std::endl;
     std::cout << "ARGSPROC's size is: " << sizeof(ARGSPROC) << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, Both used 8 bytes of memory. I understood how gl3w was able to switch between the array and the struct, they used the same amount of memory. The array was simply a tool allowing the functions to be assigned to in an easier fashion. I knew the code worked and understood that they didn't consume different amounts of memory, but I didn't know why. So that's my question: Why don't function pointer arguments affect memory size?

Comment: Becaue a fuction pointer is simply the address in memory to which control is transferred when you call the function. And a pointer is the same size irrespective of the details of the function parameters (or anything else about the function).

Comment: Put it another way, checks on the type of any function parameters are made by the compiler at compile time, not by the program at run time. Therefore a function pointer does not need to store any information about the parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function pointer is still just a pointer, i.e. it contains a memory address.

It doesn't contain anything about what the pointer points to.  That's part of the language, not the representation of a pointer.

Comment: Are those statements necessarily true in C++ (have they been made part of the standard)? Say some C++ implementation wants to implement authenticated pointers for functions, and that requires that function pointers contain more bits than object pointers. Does the C++ standard prohibit that? Does it prohibit having information in the pointers about what the pointer points to?

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to different types *may* have different sizes, and it is possible for a pointer to a function taking no arguments to have a different size and/or alignment from a pointer to a function taking some number of arguments (I can't imagine why they would, but it's possible).  It's also possible for them to have the *same* size and alignment.

Whether they do or not depends *entirely* on the specific implementation.  On systems with a "flat" memory model (modern Windows, MacOS, and Linux on x86 and x86-64, for example), all object pointer and function pointer types tend to be the same size. On segmented systems like DOS you had `near` (16-bit) and `far` (32-bit) pointers depending on whether you were referencing something in the same memory segment or not.  Harvard architectures keep code and data in physically separate memory with different address bus sizes, so pointers to functions may have different sizes than pointers to objects.

In C++ the only requirements (AFAICT, anyway) are that pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as pointers to their unqualified equivalent, and that `void *` and `char *` have the same size and alignment.

You should never be surprised if two different pointer types have the same size.  You should never be surprised if two different pointer types have different sizes (modulo the requirements above).

Answer (score 0):

this is because it is just a pointer like any pointer but points to function with a specific signature so that the compiler can deduce how to make a call in the call site . A pointer is typically a number containing the address of the object it points to , an it (the pointer) has the size of the cpu arch the program is compiled for . so x64 pointers are 8 bytes = 64 bits, x32 pointers are 4 bytes = 32 bits and so on